# Connect Eclipse to Websphere Liberty in another computer

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere-liberty

I had installed Websphere Liberty Runtime in a Windows 7 machine following the instructions here :
  https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-non-eclipse-environments/

I had installed and configured the admin-center feature following these instructions :
   http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_ui_setup.html

I set two users : admin and nonadmin

I am able to connect to this server from Eclipse in another computer.
 However, each time i try to deploy an application on this server, i get this error in the computer with Eclipse :

```
Publish HelloWorldApplication
OK
Failed to transfer application HelloWorldApplication
CWWKX0121E: Access denied to path C:/wlp/usr/servers/servername/apps/HelloWorldApplication.war.
Failed to synchronize server configuration.
CWWKX0121E: Access denied to path C:/wlp/usr/servers/servername/server.xml.
Deployment of application HelloWorldApplication failed.
```

And, in the server i got this :

```
[ERROR   ] CWWKX7901E: The C:/wlp/usr/servers/servername/apps/HelloWorldApplication.war file system path is not valid.
```

Can anyone help me, please ?
We are more than one developer needing to work on this server.

Thanks in advance.
    SJRM

Comment: The path really exists and the user running the server (I suspect the Liberty Server) can access that folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you have your server.xml configured? Given the error you mention, I think it's missing the configuration for writing into the remote directories, which looks something like this:

```
<remoteFileAccess>
    <writeDir>${writePath}</writeDir>
</remoteFileAccess>
```

You can define several write directories and each one can refer to variables or absolute paths, for example:

```
<remoteFileAccess>
    <writeDir>${wlp.user.dir}</writeDir>
</remoteFileAccess>
```

You can obtain the basic configuration for remote administration by executing this command on you Liberty profile bin directory:

```
configUtility install remoteAdministration
```

For reference see:

- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/t_creating_remote_server.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5%2F1-3-11-0-2-3 for setting up a remote server,
- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_command_configutil.html%23rwlp_command_configutil?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5%2F1-3-11-0-3-2-1-1&lang=en for reading about the configUtility and
- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_dirs.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5%2F1-3-11-0-2-0&lang=en for a list of Liberty profile properties and their corresponding directories.